# sizeof operator gives wrong value for an array

Tags: c++

Can Someone explain why `sizeof` operator gives wrong return in value in following code in c++. Although the expected answer was 6, the final output was 7.

```
char word[]="SanCha";
cout << sizeof(text);
```

Comment: I would expect this code not to compile at all.

Comment: Because of the terminating '\0'. The variable name was `word`, not `text`.

Comment: By convention, a string literal is represented as a (statically) allocated array of `char` with a terminating nul (with numeric value zero) character.   So `"SanCha"` is represented as an array with elements `{'S', 'a', 'n', 'C', 'h', 'a', '\0'};` which has size `7`, not `6`.   C++ inherited this from C, hence need for functions like `strcmp()`, `strlen()`, `strcpy()`, `strcat()`, etc to work with string literals and arrays of `char` that represent similar strings.